# MIPS Input floating point number

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

How do you take in an input of a floating number in MIPS? I have tried using:

```
li.s $f0, 6 
syscall
```

But I just keep getting that there is an error with the line.

Comment: The system call number goes in `$v0`, not `$f0`. It the result _after_ the syscall that ends up in `$f0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**li $v0, 6**

**syscall**

**//the float value that is read will be in $f0 register**

Answer (score 1):

you cannot load-immediate a number into float registers

```
li $t0, 6           # load-immediate 6 into an int register
mtc1 $t0, $f0       # copies the bit pattern "...110". It is NOT 6.0!!
cvt.s.w. $f12, $f0  # convert word to (single) float. $f12 now contains 6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also place the float in the data segment:

```
.data
  pi: .float 3.1415926535 # place value of pi in the data segment
.text
  lwc1 $f12, pi           # load pi from data segment into $f12
  li $v0, 2
  syscall                 # print $f12
```

Output will be:

```
3.1415927
-- program is finished running
```